# How to process matrix multiplication in python?

Tags: python

this program will get the basic informations one by one(input row, column, row, column)
then the numbers(numbers in first matrix orderd by column, in second, ordered by row)

so, if the first matrix like this will be listed as `A.[1,2,3,4]`

```
1 2

3 4
```

and the second one will be `B.[5,7,6,8]`

```
5 6 

7 8
```

and I made number of row of first matrix as num1 of column as num2

row of second matrix as num3 (num3 should equal to num2 to calculate) of column as num4

its result will be like this no matter how big of the matrices

```
A[0]*B[0]+A[1]*B[1]     A[0]*B[2]+A[1]*B[3]

A[2]*B[0]+A[3]*B[1]     A[2]*B[2]+A[3]*B[3]
```

so I have to code this where I'm stuck in :

```
while j in B(j) increases until j reaches `(num3*num4-1)`,
```

i in A(i) should increase and repeat the `interval(0, num2-1)`

so result will be `res += int(A[i]) * int(B[j])`

when j reaches `(num3*num4-1)`, it should go back to 0 and repeat these process until i reaches `(num1*num2-1)`

```
if num2 == num3:
res=0
for k in range(0, num2):
    for i in range(k, ):
for l in range(0, (num4)-1):    
    for j in range(l*num2, (l+1)*(num2)-1):
        res += int(a[i])*int(b[j])

        c.append(res)

    k+=1
```

Comment: would you prefer to keep your inputs as 1 dimensional arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation that keeps the inputs in a flat array structure as you initially intended. It could be a good idea to check not only that `num2 == num3` but also that `len(a) % num2 == 0` and that `len(b) % num3 == 0`

```
c = []
for k in range(0, len (a)/num2):
    for i in range(0, len (b)/num3):
            res = 0
            for n in range(0,num2):
                   j = num3*i + n
                   l = num2*k + n
                   res += int(a[l]*b[j])
                   if n == num2-1:
                       c.append(res)
```

Comment: thank you very much! your code is really clear and it was easy to understand.

Comment: No problem! Don't forget to mark in answer if you feel your question has indeed been answered :-)

Answer (score 2):

Matrix multiplication can be done easily using NumPy package.

```
a = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
b = [[4, 1], [2, 2]]
np.matmul(a, b)
```

The result of multiplication would be an Array.

```
array([[4, 1],[2, 2]])
```

If you want to do it old for loop way then iterating through columns and rows to multiply and then adding values will result in matrix multiplication as in below code.

```
# Program to multiply two matrices using nested loops

# 2 * 2 matrix
X = [[1, 2],
    [3, 4]]
# 2 * 2 matrix
Y = [[5,6],
    [7,8]]
# result is 2 * 2
result = [[0,0,],
         [0,0,]]

# iterate through rows of X
for i in range(len(X)):
   # iterate through columns of Y
   for j in range(len(Y[0])):
       # iterate through rows of Y
       for k in range(len(Y)):
           result[i][j] += X[i][k] * Y[k][j]

for r in result:
   print(r)
```

Result will be

```
[19, 22]
[43, 50]
```

Comment: thank you very much to let me know the easy way. I'll try NumPy later!

Comment: I guess then you need to do this multiplication in plain Python?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

```
import numpy


def matrix_multiplier(auxA, auxB):
    print (numpy.matmul(auxA,auxB))


#[1, 2]
#[3, 4]
auxA = numpy.array([[A[0], A[1]],[A[2], A[3]]])
#[5, 6]
#[7, 8]
auxB = numpy.array([B[0], B[1]],[B[2], B[3]])

matrix_multiplier(auxA,auxB)
```

Which gives the result:

```
[[19 22]
 [43 50]]
```

Comment: yes please! as a beginner, I really want to build something from nothing! thank you!